# How do I plot Log [1/x] from Log [x]?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Is there a way of plotting `Log [1/x]` from a `Log [x]` function?

I'm plotting this:

```
Plot[{lnKpexp, lnKpest}, {T, 200, 1600}, PlotRange -> {-100, 0}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {200, -100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Blue}}]
```

[image]

where `lnKpexp` and `lnKpest` are Log functions.

I want to linearize it.

Comment: Could you give us definitions for your two functions? Without them your question is ambiguous.

Comment: Are you talking about using the identity, Log[1/x]=-Log[x]?

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions I believe that [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) will do what you want, though undocumented:

```
Plot[7 + Log[3 x], {x, 200, 1600}, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, {Exp, Log}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment on Mr.Wizard's answer than an answer.

I think Mr.Wizard is answer is likely correct, but my interpretation is that the OP is really looking for a different scaling, something like

```
Plot[Log[1/(3 x + 1)], {x, 200, 1600}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, {Exp[-#] &, -Log[#] &}}]
```

[image: plot]

Also, the technique is not completely undocumented; a relevant example can be found under ref/Plot > Options > Scaling Functions. It is the 3rd example from the bottom of the section.

Comment: See my comment posted as an another answer.